# Create two random teams from a list of players

Tags: c#, array, random

The task is to create two random teams from a list of players.

Given an example of players = `["John", "Mike", "Alice", "Bob"]`

One example random team would be:

```
team1 = ["Mike", "Alice"];
team2 = ["John", "Bob"];
```

This is my solution but I'm not sure how efficient it is because random can create same number for a number of times.

The question to separate equally and randomly without repeating the same player.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var numbers = new List<int>();

        var ilkListe = new List<int>();

        var ikinciListe = new List<int>();

        numbers.Add(1);
        numbers.Add(2);
        numbers.Add(3);
        numbers.Add(4);
        numbers.Add(5);
        numbers.Add(6);
        numbers.Add(7);
        numbers.Add(8);
        numbers.Add(9);
        numbers.Add(10);
        Console.WriteLine("LIST 1: " + numbers.Count);

        do {
            int sayi = numbers[rnd.Next(numbers.Count)];
            if (!(ilkListe.Contains(sayi))) {
                Console.WriteLine(sayi);
                ilkListe.Add(sayi);
            }
        }

        while (ilkListe.Count < numbers.Count / 2);

        Console.WriteLine("Ikinci liste");

        do {
            int sayi = numbers[rnd.Next(numbers.Count)];
            if (!(ilkListe.Contains(sayi)) && !(ikinciListe.Contains(sayi))) {
                Console.WriteLine(sayi);
                ikinciListe.Add(sayi);
            }
        }

        while (ikinciListe.Count < numbers.Count / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating. I've looked through your code and it does seem like it does what it is supposed to do but in an inefficient way, so you've come to the right place.

Comment: @dfhwze it does not matter actually. The idea is same. I was just trying to simulate the task in an online editor.

Comment: I don't have time today to write an answer, but you should consider shuffling the array, then dividing into the two teams.  That completes in deterministic time, whereas there's no guarantee that the presented algorithm will terminate.

Comment: @Toby Speight thank you. "shuffling the array"  do too much.

Comment: Actually: better than shuffling is simply to iterate through the elements, and assign each to a team (with 50% probability) until one of the teams is fully populated (effectively, a partial shuffle).

Comment: @TobySpeight: Your suggestion might work for the OP and it might not. Consider this... There are 100 players listed alphabetically. Using your suggestion, Xavier and Zak will almost always be on the same team, a violation of the OP's "random teams" condition.

Comment: A [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle of an N-element array is bounded linear time, N-1 random calls. Once you have done that, a lot of problems including this one are trivial.

Comment: @Patricia, if implementing a Fisher-Yates shuffle (rather than using a library one), it's possible to stop after reaching element N/2, since the remaining steps serve only to re-order team 2.

Comment: @TobySpeight True. This is a special case of a problem for which I've used a truncated F-Y in the past, pick a random k element subset from an N element array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your new solution does look somewhat better than the original, I would suggest that constantly removing elements from the list can be quite expensive.  I would suggest shuffling or randomly sorting the list then simply divvying up the players to the teams.

Also you're still putting the implementation in Main, instead of calling a method.

Instead of hardcoding everything for 2 teams I would be in favor of allowing any number of teams as long as it's an exact divisor of the number of players.

Instead of multidimensional lists, I would use a Dictionary where the Key is the name of the team and the players names are in a list.

It could look something like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int,List<T>> MakeTeams<T>(this List<T> playerList, int numTeams)
{

    int count = playerList.Count();
    if(count % numTeams != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The number of players must be a multiple of numTeams to get even distribution of players");
    }
    var randomList = playerList.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
    var teams = (from int i in Enumerable.Range(0, count)
                 let item = randomList[i]
                 group item by (i % numTeams) into team
                 select team).ToDictionary(team => team.Key, team => team.ToList());

    return teams;
}
```

This simply uses a number for the team name.  If you wanted to get fancier with it you could add a string array of team names to use instead:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<T>> MakeTeams<T>(this List<T> playerList, int numTeams, string[] teamNames)
{
    if(teamNames.Length < numTeams)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The number of team names must be equal to or greater than numTeams");
    }
    int count = playerList.Count();
    if (count % numTeams != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The number of players must be a multiple of numTeams to get even distribution of players");
    }
    var randomList = playerList.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
    var teams = (from int i in Enumerable.Range(0, count)
                 let item = randomList[i]
                 group item by (i % numTeams) into team
                 select team).ToDictionary(team => teamNames[team.Key], team => team.ToList());

    return teams;
}
```

Comment: Couple of things: Make the dictionary keys a generic type as well. Don't ask how many teams there are, just count how many keys you were given. Don't use random-guid-sort to shuffle ([lengthy discussion in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262134/10135377)).

Comment: I've seen `OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())` repeatedly and it's an awful solution to shuffle a list. Not only is it non-intuitive, it's also slow, not guaranteed to work at all (there's no guarantee what type of GUID is created, the GUID only has to be unique) and worst of all it's subtly broken. A fisher yates shuffle is trivial to implement so don't skimp to save a few lines of code. (Using a proper PRNG for your random shuffle property is also wrong, so no just stick with fisher yates)

Answer (score 18):

#### Review

- Don't use the main entry point to implement an algorithm. Create a method instead.
- Think about how to allow this method to be usable for all kinds of types, not just integers. You have implemented the algorithm for integers, yet you show an example with strings.
- When creating an algorithm, surely you have made some unit tests, at least for the happy paths. Feel free to include them in the question.
- Use clear variable names, and stick to one written language.
- Don't mix algorithm logic with Console output.

A possible method signature could be:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitRandom<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int targetCount)
{
    // .. algorithm implementation
}
```

Called as..

```
var names = new [] { "John", "Mike", "Alice", "Bob" };
var teams = names.SplitRandom(2);
```

Or as..

```
var numbers = Enumrable.Range(1, 10);
var numberGroups = numbers.SplitRandom(2);
```

Comment: I don't think IEnumerable is the correct signature. You need the length of the data and also to shuffle the data, too. So what you need is actually IReadOnlyCollection<T>. And the result is IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<T>> (I'm not sure about the output type).

Answer (score 5):

All of [dfhwze](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/225292/200133)'s points are spot-on, and the only thing I can think of to add to his type-signature is that if you're unfamiliar with all of the syntax he's using *that's ok*.
<sub>(If you want to learn the stuff in question, search for "inheritance" (or "interface"), "generics", "extension methods", and possibly "generators" or "yield".)</sub>

### Regarding your actual algorithm:

The **big red flag** that your current algorithm isn't good is that you have two nearly-identical loops. That they happen to be `while` loops is a **small red flag**, which you noticed indirectly when you noted that `rnd.Next()` can yield duplicates.

The algorithm you probably want is to first **shuffle** your source list, and then take sequential runs from it as needed.
Stack Exchange gives us usable implementations of both those steps. Only copy-paste them if you understand how they work and you want those exact methods lying around your code-base; most of the time it's better to re-write these things so that you're making the "details" decisions for yourself.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22668974/10135377) gives us a nice implementation of [The Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle), which is efficient and appropriate.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396143/10135377) gives us tidy slicing. (What *exactly* happens if `source.Count / (Double)size` isn't an integer?)

There are some details that *probably* matter, like whether or not the original order of the elements needs to be preserved, or what should happen if the source list isn't evenly divisible into the number of buckets in question.

And once you've resolved all of that, since you asked about efficiency, we can return to [dfhwze](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/225292/200133)'s function signature. Specifically, `this IEnumerable<T> source` is taken as an enumer**able** collection; the Fisher–Yates shuffle shuffles a list **in place**. It's *very tempting* to change the argument to `this IList<T> source`, so that if the calling context already has a list, we're can just use that one instead of calling `source.ToList()`. If you do it that way you'll have written a function that returns a computed value *and* modifies the contents of its argument; **strongly consider not doing that**.

Comment: If you are looking for an efficient implementation I would probably just loop through the list once and randomly assign each player to one team, until one team is full, then all remaining players go to the other team. No shuffling and no reallocations.

Comment: @Falco: Your suggestion might work for the OP and it might not.  Consider this... There are 100 players listed alphabetically.  Using your suggestion, Xavier and Zak will almost always be on the same team, a violation of the OP's "random teams" condition.

Comment: You are right, most simpler solutions have unwanted correlations between some players landing in the same team depending on position in the list. An inplace-shuffle and then taking two sub-lists is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> players = new List<string>(new string[]{ "John", "Mike", "Kate", "Michael" });

        List<string> randomPlayers = ShuffleList<string>(players);

        List<string> team1 = randomPlayers.GetRange(0, (randomPlayers.Count - 1) / 2);
        List<string> team2 = randomPlayers.GetRange((randomPlayers.Count - 1) / 2, (randomPlayers.Count - 1));
    }

    public static List<E> ShuffleList<E>(List<E> inputList)
    {
     List<E> randomList = new List<E>();

     Random r = new Random();
     int randomIndex = 0;
     while (inputList.Count > 0)
     {
          randomIndex = r.Next(0, inputList.Count); //Choose a random object in the list
          randomList.Add(inputList[randomIndex]); //add it to the new, random list
          inputList.RemoveAt(randomIndex); //remove to avoid duplicates
     }

     return randomList; //return the new random list
    }
}
```

After a little search of "array shuffle keyword", rewrite the code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Just a friendly reminder that self-answers should still be in the form of a _review_ - you're expected to explain what's wrong with the original code, rather than simply posting a replacement.  You'll find more guidance in the [help] (sorry, I don't have time to look it up for you right now - I'm in the middle of a very busy spell).

Comment: A quick and easy way I sometimes use to shuffle a list, is to simply order it by NewGuid. So you could do `randomPlayers = players.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());`

Comment: @dbso; I won't argue that order-by-guid isn't _quick and easy to write_, but it's too hacky to inline without comment, and if you're going to have a designated method for the task then you should do it correctly. The comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262134/10135377) discuss your suggestion, and the other answers there show better ways of shuffling in place.

Comment: That's an unnecessarily O(n^2) implementation of a linear problem. The splitting up afterwards is also incorrect.